# Models where HABTM exists for all of the child models in search_array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose `search_array = [1, 3, 6]` and `Model` has_and_belongs_to_many `ChildModels`

I want to return `Models` which have as HABTM link to **all** of the `ChildModels` in `search_array`.

**My code, for those that asked**

```
# Find drivers where driver has ALL OF the availables in the array
chunk = start
block_ids = []
while chunk <= ending
  block_ids << Block.where(hour: chunk.hour, day: chunk.wday).take.id
  chunk += 1.hour
end
drivers = drivers.where( availables: block_ids ) # This line is the issue
```

Currently, the code will find drivers where the driver has ANY OF the availables in the array block_ids

Comment: After reading the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) about querying ActiveRecord objects, where are you stuck? Please show the code you have written yet and describe what your exact problems are.

Comment: Code included above.